# If Else combined with a Boolean doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm Spawning some objects and I have two type of Collisions, with the floor or with the Toilette (Player). If the object collides first with the floor then there's a delay and destroy, but If it touches the Toilette (Player) 2 things could happen:

1. direct touch, destroy.
2. bounce after touching floor, is not destroyed by the toilette but with the delay previously mentioned.

So the if else with the boolean collisionHappened (true or false) is not working, I mean, the floor works fine, when the objects touches the floor, they're destroyed, but when they touch the Player, nothing happens. Something is wrong with my code:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision target)
{
    collisionHappened = true;

    if (target.gameObject.tag.Equals("bathroomFloor") == true && collisionHappened)
    {
        StartCoroutine(WaitToDestroy());

    }

    if (target.gameObject.tag.Equals("superToilette") == true)
    {
        if (collisionHappened)
        {

        }
        else if (collisionHappened != true)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            GameObject.Find("scoreBoardText").GetComponent<ScoreBoard>().duringGameScoreIncreaser++;
        }
    }
}
```

Some suggestions? thanks guys!

Comment: Just a heads up that it should be `if(!collisionHappened)` -- that is easier to read. and you don't even need it since a boolean can only have two states. Just use `}else{`

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `== true`.

So:

```
if (target.gameObject.tag.Equals("bathroomFloor") == true && collisionHappened)
```

Becomes:

```
if (target.gameObject.tag.Equals("bathroomFloor") && collisionHappened)
```

Also, you set collisionHappened = true at the top, so you can remove that too, resulting in:

```
if (target.gameObject.tag.Equals("bathroomFloor"))
 // Do some stuff
```

Also, you do nothing if the collision is with the (super)Toilette

```
if (collisionHappened)
{
   // Handle the collision here 
}
```

Comment: thanks Murray :D at the end solved with the code bellow :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (collisionHappened)
    {

    }
else if (collisionHappened != true)
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
        GameObject.Find("scoreBoardText").GetComponent<ScoreBoard>().duringGameScoreIncreaser++;
    }
```

The else if is unnecessary. it can be replaces with an else and do the same thing, like so:

```
if (collisionHappened)
    {

    }
else
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
        GameObject.Find("scoreBoardText").GetComponent<ScoreBoard>().duringGameScoreIncreaser++;
    }
```

Else in this case is already "if collisionHappend != true." Since there is only two states for the boolean to be in, an if else will work just fine

Comment: thanks at the end this didn't worked for me :( solved and uploaded the code :D!!

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved myself. I didn't required the if else statement. Only Ifs, Introduced the boolean as true in the Start and then simply changed from true to false if the object hits first the floor, that way if it hits the floor, the player can't destroy it nor gain points! here the code!!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PDestroy : MonoBehaviour
{
public float destroyDelay;
public Rigidbody pRigidBody;
[SerializeField] bool collisionHappened;


private void Start()
{
    destroyDelay = 0.3f;
    collisionHappened = true;
    pRigidBody = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    pRigidBody.AddForce(Random.Range(90, -90), transform.position.y 
,transform.position.z);
}

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision target)
{
    if (target.gameObject.tag.Equals("bathroomFloor"))
    {
        if (collisionHappened)
        {
            StartCoroutine(WaitToDestroy());
            collisionHappened = false;
        }
    }

    if (target.gameObject.tag.Equals("superToilette"))
    {
        if (collisionHappened)
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            GameObject.Find("scoreBoardText").GetComponent<ScoreBoard>. 
().duringGameScoreIncreaser++;
        }
    }
}

IEnumerator WaitToDestroy()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(destroyDelay);
    Destroy(this.gameObject);
}
}
```